# Sass map loop possibilities

Tags: css, loops, dictionary, sass

I have a pretty long sass map, which as a fragment is ([full code in Codepen](http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/oXNZEb)):

```
$pbcolors: (

pbcyan : (
50:  #E5F5FC,
100: #CCEBF9,
200: #99D7F2,
300: #66C3EC,
400: #33AFE5,
500: #009DBF,
600: #008CAB,
700: #007C98,
800: #006D85,
900: #005D72
),
pbmediumblue: (
50:  #E5F1F8,
100: #CCE3F1,
200: #99C7E3,
300: #66AAD4,
400: #338EC6,
500: #0072B8,
600: #0065A5,
700: #005A93,
800: #004F80,
900: #00436E
),
pbpurple: (
50:  #F5ECF5,
100: #ECD9EB,
200: #D9B2D7,
300: #C68CC3,
400: #B365AF,
500: #A03F9B,
600: #90388B,
700: #80327C,
800: #702C6C,
900: #60255D
);
```

I am trying to write a loop to create a series of classes named after the color and the shade with the bg color as the hex, like so

```
.bg-pbmediumblue-100 { background: #CCE3F1; }
```

However, my syntax must be broken since I'm not making the leap to the second level:

```
@each $item, $color in $pbcolors {
  @each $shade, $value in $item {
    .bg-#{$shade}-#{$shade} {
      background-color: map-get(map-get($pbcolors, $item), 50);
    }
  }
}
```

From this I get ONLY the 50 of each color, and the wrong class name:

```
.bg-pbcyan-pbcyan {
   background-color: #E5F5FC;
 }

.bg-pbmediumblue-pbmediumblue {
   background-color: #E5F1F8;
 }
```

What did I screw up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong variable.  The `$item` variable (first) references the mapping *key* name, not the *value* (second).  You need to iterate over the value in your inner loop.

```
@each $item, $color in $pbcolors {
  @each $shade, $value in $color {
    .bg-#{$item}-#{$shade} {
      background-color: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd still love to know how to make that loop, I wound up using a function instead and we can call the tints when needed instead of printing them all out whether needed or not.

```
@function pbcolor($pbcolor, $tone: 500) {
   @return map-get(map-get($pbcolors, $pbcolor), $tone);
}
```

This way, it's simple to get the color on demand:

```
.oneway {
  color: pbcolor(pbcyan, 500);
 }
```

or even

```
.oneway {
  color: pbcolor(pbcyan);
 }
```

to get the default 500 shade.